# Como detectar tentativa de intrusão?

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-injection

A fim de proteger contra injeção SQL, preciso elaborar uma função no qual elimine a possibilidade de alguém que tente agir de má fé.

A dúvida é, `mysqli` traz consigo alguma funcionalidade para ajudar a ir contra isso? E além disso, qual seria a melhor forma, isto é, a melhor função para dar conta de eliminar a possibilidade de SQL injection?

Comment: Também tive a mesma impressão @jbueno

Answer (score 11):

Prevenir-se contra ataques, às vezes é fácil, e às vezes é difícil, isso dependendo do conhecimento de quem está a criar essas barreiras. Atualmente existem várias bibliotecas do tipo *Open Source* pela internet, capazes de lidar com uma boa parte dos ataques até hoje elaborados.

Quanto as funções/bibliotecas *"padrão"* se posso assim dizer, atualmente, existem apenas o *MySQLi* e o *PDO*.

**MySQLi** ou *MySQL improved*, é uma versão melhorada do *MySQL*, atualmente com suporte para o estilo *orientado a objetos* e *procedual* , ambos eficazes.

**PDO** ou *PHP Data Objects* é uma extensão que permite conectar com bancos de dados, além de fornecer abstração destas camadas. O *PDO* por padrão suporta diversos bancos de dados.

Qual usar, é algo a ser escolhido por que vai programar, porque ambas têm diversas utilidades, e às vezes, dependendo da situação, é mais fácil trabalhar com uma à outra.

Quanto a *injeção de SQL*, ambas vêm bem preparadas para estes tipos de ataques.

Tanto o *MySQLi* como o *PDO* possuem *prepared statments* e *stored procedures*, eficazes e reduzem imenso o risco de haver uma *injeção de SQL*.

**Prepared Statments & Stored Procedures:**

- A Query é passada uma única vez, e pode ser executada várias vezes, com diferentes parâmetros.
- Quando a Query é *preparada*, ela é compilada e otimizada para executar.
- Quanto maior a Query, maior o tempo para compilar e otimizar.
- Os parâmetros não precisam de *"aspas"*, são automaticamente processados pelo driver.

**Exemplo PDO:**

```
<?php
/* Connect to an MySQL database using driver invocation */
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=localhost';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);

// insert one row
$name = 'one';
$value = 1;
$stmt->execute();

// insert another row with different values
$name = 'two';
$value = 2;
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

Com o *PDO* normalmente deve-se instanciar a classe num bloco **try/catch**, para capturar a exceção, no caso de haver alguma.

**Exemplo MySQLi:**

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$city = "Amersfoort";

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $city);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($district);

    /* fetch value */
    $stmt->fetch();

    printf("%s is in district %s\n", $city, $district);

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

O facto de utilizar este drivers não faz com que estejas blindado contra as pessoas mal intencionadas, porque dependendo do que faças no teu script de conexão/busca/inserção, se não souberes como tratar dos dados de entrada *(dados normalmente enviados pelo utilizador à partir de formulários, campos de busca, etc.)* vais sempre ter estes problemas.

> The developer can be sure that no SQL injection will occur (however, if other portions of the query are being built up with unescaped input, SQL injection is still possible).

Outra coisa, é que... não interessa o quanto tentes, porque se alguém realmente quiser trapacear o teu sistema, simplesmente o vai fazer, o importante é colocares um nível de segurança para o tipo de sistema que se quer usar, porque é meio ilógico, imagina - *proteger um estabelecimento de jogos infantis frequentado apenas por crianças de 5 anos, com a segurança de uma casa de jogos adultos*.

Se quiseres segurança, e scripts de confiança, existem vários por aí, criados e avaliados por profissionais, e são *Open Source*, lembra-te apenas disto.

**Algumas Referências:**

- [Prepared Statments & Stored Procedures - PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)
- [PDO Construct - PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)
- [MySQLi Prepared Statments - PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: +1 Boa resposta e mais completa que a minha!

Comment: Ohh, agradecido !

Answer (score 7):

A forma recomendada de acesso a Bancos de Dados é usando o **mysqli** ou **PDO**, conforme a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

No caso do **mysqli**, a função [`prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) permite o uso de *prepared statements*, onde a consulta (*query*) é enviada ao servidor separadamente dos parâmetros ou variáveis.

Exemplo baseado na documentação:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$cidade = "Sorocaba";

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Estado FROM Cidade WHERE Nome=?")) {  
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $cidade);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($estado);
    $stmt->fetch();

    printf("%s fica no estado de %s\n", $cidade, $estado);

    $stmt->close();
}

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Lembre-se que *SQL Injection* é apenas um dos possíveis tipos de ataque baseado em dados enviados. Todo e qualquer dado recebido do usuário precisa ser verificado e "escapado" de acordo com o contexto, por exemplo:

- Se usar dados para executar comandos no sistema, o atacante pode ganhar acesso ao sistema, portanto "escape" caracteres de controle.
- Se exibir dados do usuário numa tela HTML, "escape" caracteres especiais, caso contrário o usuário pode injetar um script e coletar dados dos outros usuários.
- Se gravar dados em arquivos, por exemplo, um log, é preciso ter cuidado porque um usuário malicioso pode injetar linhas adicionais no log.

Enfim, é importante ter uma visão clara do que se faz com os dados do usuário para identificar perigos em potencial.